# Reduce number of bands in GeoTIFF

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

I'm in a bit of deep water here since I'm not very familiar with GeoTIFF.

I have tried to set transparency to a GeoTIFF layer in GeoServer but when I set this I get a error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BandCombine: Input matrix has wrong dimensions`

and that error seems to occur when the image has more then three bands. If I understand it correctly this image seems to have 5 bands.

Is there is some way to redcue these 5 bands to 3 so that I can set transparancy in GeoServer on this layer?

Comment: what does your SLD file look like?

Comment: I use the default "raster sld" in Geoserver.

Comment: so how did you set the transparency?

Comment: I used the "Input transparant color" setting on the layer in Geoserver. I think that has worked before on some other tiff-layers. But I might be wrong on that, it was some time since I did this on some other layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a custom SLD to select which bands to use in your WMS response which will always be RGBA.

A `RasterSymbolizer` can have a [`ChannelSelection`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#channelselection) section

```
<ChannelSelection>
  <RedChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
  </RedChannel>
  <GreenChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
  </GreenChannel>
  <BlueChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
  </BlueChannel>
</ChannelSelection>
```

More advanced options include using [environment variables](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#channelselection-expressions).